# PrimeNG - How to remove 'p-tabview' elements(<a>, <ul> elements) which are dynamically getting rendered on Angular UI?

Tags: html, angular

I am on a angular 4 project where i used p-tabview. In p-tabview I want to remove `` tags for a particular condition, in which these tags are dynamically getting rendered in DOM  but are not visible in UI code.[The `<ul>, <li> & <a>`tag elements which are highlighted in the image are dynamically getting rendered in DOM. I want to remove the focused element which is highlighted in yellow on the UI page. I can achieve this, by removing the above tags which are dynamically getting rendered, but I could find the appropriate code in my local angular code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quPjW.png)

**Local Angular Code of UI:**

`<p-tabView>
 <p-tabPanel header="{{recommendationModel.displayName}}" (keydown)="recommTabKeyhandle($event, 
   recommendationModel.displayName);" [selected]="recommendationResultData.length > 0 ? true : false">
   <span *ngIf="entityName !=constDHSEntity">`

**Below is CODE Dynamically getting rendered in DOM FOR p-tabview** :

`<p-tabview>
  <div class="ui-tabview ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-tabview-top">
   <ul p-tabviewnav="" role="tablist" class="ui-tabview-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
    <li role="presentation" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabview-selected ui-state-active">
     <a href="#" role="tab" id="ui-tabpanel-0-label" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="ui-tabpanel-0">
        <span class="ui-tabview-title"></span>
     </a>
    </li>
 </ul>`

I want to hide `<a>,<ul> & <li>` tag elements in the above dynamically rendered code for a specific condition. How to remove this from the local angular UI code where I couldn't find these tags?